# Поменять надпись в форме

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

В вордпрессе использую связку плагинов contact form 7 и mailpoet для автоподписки по заявке. Не могу найти, где изменить надпись "Sign up for the newsletter".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я почти уверен, что это меняется как обычный label в двойных кавычках [mailpoetsignup "test"]. Если не помогло, то альтернативный вариант через gettext https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-on-contact-form-7-mailpoet-3-change-text/

Comment: @noname228 проверил, не помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну это надо в файлах плагина искать, либо в файлах перевода.
Я в такой ситуации выкачивал архив и через редактор искал фразу по всем файлам в папке.

Comment: спасибо, помогло, не там искал, plugins/add-on-contact-form-7-mailpoet/includes/class-mailpoet-cf7-integration.php был тут, вдруг пригодится кому

Comment: @Anario это неправильный способ. Правильный второй - в переводе. Т.е. в ланпаке.https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/add-on-contact-form-7-mailpoet/dev/ru/default/?filters%5Boriginal_id%5D=5043742